# Batch edit pdf - change Page Layout and Magnification with Automator Action or AppleScript

Tags: pdf, applescript, automator

Just wondering if there is a way to batch edit pdf documents and set the "Page Layout" and "Magnification" attribute of a document so that they all the documents are displayed the same way if you open them.

I'm a Mac so a Automator  or AppleScript solution would be cool! BTW I have Acrobat Pro.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

this could be done with some really hard work via gui script (NOT recommended) or by way of javascript which has it's complications as well but is much more reliable than gui scripting you will need the the [javascript reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html) to learn how to do the javscript part of the script and you will have to research how to run the js in your applescript if you have questions I'll be happy to try to help but I'm not just gonna hand you the code to this job.