# What is the most straightforward way of modifying PDF start-up options via C#?

Tags: c#, pdf

I'd like to know what would be the most straightforward (i.e., preferably without adding DLLs to my solution) way to write a C# code snippet for modifying a PDF document's page layout and magnification options.

I know this is incredibly easy in LaTeX (well, it's easy to set these for a PDF to-be-generated using a single package) through `hyperref` options.

Modifying an already-created PDF document is a lot more work however. Also, most MS Office print-to-PDF options don't seem to include this ability while it's obviously annoying to keep opening documents up in Acrobat and manually modifying these for the proper (desired) opening settings (layout: single page, and magnification: fit page, for me).

So, I would like to write a code snippet that could do this. **What is the most straightforward way of modifying PDF start-up options via C#?**

Alternatively, is there a way to force-apply these options when generating PDFs from MS Office software suites?

I looked into PDFSharp and MigraDoc at one point for PDF-making from C#, but that really didn't match what I was hoping for. Plus, it added a DLL set (of ten dependencies) which was sub-optimal with respect to how many ancillary files were included with the build for managing a relatively simple function.

However, as noted in the comments, such a batch modification code is likely to be very difficult without any dependencies, so I'll also accept answers which reference dependencies.

Past topics (but not very good matches):

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368972/batch-edit-pdf-change-page-layout-and-magnification-with-automator-action-or-a) is similar but for JavaScript, and actually suggests it shouldn't be done.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222048/set-pdf-page-layout-to-twopageleft-using-javascript-acrobat-pro) is a bit more elaborate for JavaScript, but not exactly what I am looking for.
- [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323882/set-the-default-page-layout-of-a-pdf-file-with-dompdf) seems to be this question for PHP but including some external references...

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that information not saved inside the PDF. The PDF has no idea which magnification or layout it should use to present itself, because it doesn't present itself. Applications like Adobe Acrobat Reader and web browsers that actually display the PDF make an educated guess at what it should be, or just use your previous settings. So no, this is impossible and I see no reason why it should be

Comment: Why do you think it is "sub-optimal" to add DLLs to your project?

Comment: @PatrickTucci: I didn't necessarily mean that in a general case (for example, I'm a great fan of interoperability DLLs because they add lots of functionality), but I wouldn't like to add ten DLLs (PDFSharp...) to meet one specific small function.

Comment: @MindSwipe: PDF Reference from Adobe notes a document structure property in Section 3.6.1, Document Catalog, named ```PageLayout``` and ```OpenAction``` that control the opening layout and magnification. This looks to me as if it is a part of the PDF structure itself.

Comment: You learn something new everyday. Skimming the documentation there does appear to be some information as to how a pdf reader should open a pdf file. But there is still no easy and simple **and** robust way to do it without relying on external dependencies like ITextSharp or Aspose. You could technically open the pdf file as plain text, and search and replace your way around, but I do not recommend that

Comment: Yes, that doesn't sound reasonable to me either. Very well on the external references. I'll edit in a moment to reflect the unlikeliness of it being possible as specified -- if you have an answer that would be straightforward using either of those dependencies, please do share.

Comment: @gktscrk why is it okay to add a library that that only has one or two DLLs as opposed to a library that has ten? Why is it "okay" if the external code is housed in one or two files, but it's "not okay" if the external code is contained in an arbitrarily high (ten) number of files?

Comment: @PatrickTucci: In the simplest terms, there is no difference. In a more complex level, people start asking (more) questions along with every additional DLL, especially for a simple program: "Is this really necessary? Can I run it without?" etc. I've opted for bypassing those questions in general. An additional issue is that most dependencies also obligate one to follow more copyrights & permissions things (but that's not really a problem for me; just noting that).

Comment: Don't bother. While the PDF specification does have a ViewerPreferences dictionary in the Document Catalog to control the initial view, few PDF viewers will respect those settings. Unless you have strict control over the PDF viewer that your recipients will be using, it's not worth setting those properties.